# Smooth data with missing values

Tags: r

I have a dataset (PPT.SUM) with monthly precipitation totals from 1901-2010 that takes the form:

```
Year   Month   PPT (mm)
1901    1    68.6
1901    2    54.7
1901    3    58.8
1901    4    NA
1901    5    51.9
.........................
```

I want to smooth the monthly precipitation values to show the trend more clearly. I tried using the smooth.spline function. This works well for datasets with no missing values but does not allow NA values. Is there a useful alternative smoothing function that does permit NA values? I have searched high and low for this, but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe fill in NAs with mean, or with last known value?

Comment: see `na.approx` in the zoo package.

Comment: Check out the `na.spline` function in the `zoo` package

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have gone with the na.approx method but will take a look at predicting values to complete the smooth.spline function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `na.approx()` function in the `zoo` package lets you replace `NA` values with interpolated values.

You can find more information under [this link](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/na.approx).

Depending on which type of smoothing you are aiming for, you can fill your `NAs` accordingly.